# Transform a 1xA table into a BxC table in awk

Tags: awk, getline

I am trying to turn a 1xA table into a BxC table. Let's say A is 15, B is 3 and C is 5, hence after each 5 entries I want it to start a new row in the same table.

I have a rather tedious way that appears to get close be it misses some values after each 5. I think the issue is with `RS`, as a new line forgets the "space" needed by `RS`, but I tried changing this to something else in `file.sum` and still no luck. Perhaps there is a better way to do it, but feel this should work.

```
awk -v RS=" " '{getline a1; getline a2; getline a3; getline a4; getline a5; print a1,a2,a3,a4,a5}' OFS='\t' file.sum
```

file.sum (my 1xA):

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Expected results (my BxC):

```
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15
```

Actual results:

```
1  2  3  4  5
7  8  9  10 11
13 14 15 10 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be one of the simplest solution:

```
xargs -n5 <file
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

To follow up on your `awk`.  I do not like the `getline` so I always try to avoid it. Also loop slows down `awk` some.

But using `RS=" "` you can do like this:

```
awk -v RS=" " '{$1=$1} {printf NR%5==0?"%s\n":"%s ",$0}' file
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

You can remove the `{$1=$1}`, but will then get a blank line at the end.
The `NR%5==0` test if record is every 5th and insert newline when needed.

A tab version:

```
awk -v RS=" " '{$1=$1} {printf NR%5==0?"%s\n":"%s\t",$0}' file
1       2       3       4       5
6       7       8       9       10
11      12      13      14      15
```

Comment: Always use `printf "%s", $0` rather than `printf $0` so it doesn't fail when the input contains printf formatting chars like `%s`. Also, that will probably give a syntax error in some awks due to no parens around the ternary expression and `NR%5==0?$0"\n":$0"\t"` = `$0 (NR%5?"\t":"\n")` or preferably `$0 (NR%5?OFS:ORS)` to use the variables as intended.